# Angular js way to add commas for amount based on no. of digits, once user tabs out and to auto add .00 for non decimal amount in input box

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angular.
The requirement is-

I have an input field for amount in different currency.My requirement is that ,Once user tabs out,I want the comma to get added automatically, based on number of digits in the amount.Also,if amount entered does not include a decimal value,then .00 should get auto added to the amount.

Answer (score 1):

first create an input with a directive (`add-commas` in this case)

```
<input type="text" add-commas />
```

Create a directive that registers an event handler for the inputs `blur` event like so

```
angular.module('app', [])
.directive('addCommas', function(){
  return {
    link: function(scope, el, attrs){

      el.bind('blur', function(){

        // Add the commas and stuff 
      });
    }
  }
});
```

I created a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/N78kYeFF7Fw5ktQsMdUl?p=preview) that should meet your requirements.

Hope this helps

Comment: I want the text box to accept only numbers as its an amount.Also,it should not allow more than two digits to be entered after decimal.Any clue?Rest of the things are working fine.

Comment: I updated the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/N78kYeFF7Fw5ktQsMdUl?p=preview); bear in mind that your requirements have hardly anything to do with AngularJS.

Comment: Rather than binding blur function,can i do that using ng-blur?

Comment: Sure, you can use ng-focus and ng-blur to call a scope function and modify the bound model directly like so

`<input type="text" ng-model="my_value" ng-focus="A()" ng-blur="B()" />`

 However, in that cas I would suggest to use a directive since it's much more easier to reuse


[plunker sample](http://plnkr.co/edit/tkYQ6yzIMBdPXfISwNXo)